# What type of blur was applied to this image , Box,Guassian,Laplacian, etc?

Tags: image, image-processing

[image]

I am kind of thinking it's gaussian because a box blur cannot produce that effect and i am sure its not median ? any suggestions will be appreciated , Thanks you

Comment: Based on the sharpness of the edges I'd guess that it's a median filter. What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: P.S. I think you'd have better luck asking at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree with @MarkRansom - that looks like a median filter to me too.

Comment: Mark Ransom , so u can't achieve this effect by guassian gilter ?

Comment: may be motion blur followed by median filtering?

Comment: you can try and estimate the transfer function in this case. In Fourier domain, do, output over input. Then convert back to spatial domain.

Comment: @mkuse I think it's a median filter (see my answer) - if so, FFT is unlikely to help analyse a non-linear transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just downloaded your picture, cut out the left image and used ImageJ to apply a median filter with a 15 pixel radius.

Below is the result. Conclusive?

[image: parrot]